# Legal use of an inverted (altered) version of the Stack Overflow logo

Tags: support, logo, guidelines

I would like to put an inverted version of the Stack Overflow logo on a site with black background. Is this allowed?

The trademark guidance states:

> Do not distort or alter our logo in any way.

And there is no inverted logo available for download. This suggests a "No".

However, [the original design suggestion](http://99designs.com/logo-design/contests/logo-stackoverflow-6774) was presented with both white and black backgrounds.

So I am hoping for a "Yes".

What is the official answer?

Comment: I'd say you have given the answer yourself. If it's not officially available, it's not allowed.

Comment: Are you able to tell us what you plan to do with it?

Comment: We are building a a WordPress-widget that shows our clients threads on StackOverflow. - We want to do an inverted logo as it would make Stackoverflow more prominent from the overall design of the website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off: I'm not an official representative, so my opinion is by no means a fact.

My opinion: the trademark guidance is intended to prevent usage of the logo that harms the brand or its recognizability. Just flipping the colors black and white for practical reasons - the logo wouldn't be readable otherwise - will never be considered a harmful action, it's not inherently changing it in any way. As such there should be no objection from a legal perspective to a minor alteration that is required from a design perspective, and a generally accepted way of doing so.

It's similar to using a Coca Cola jpeg on a white background with permission, and but stripping off the white background and saving it as a transparent PNG. Technically, you're altering pixels at the edges of the logo, but it doesn't harm it or change it to misrepresent the brand.

Comment: How do you know it's similar to using a cocoa cola jpeg? Are you a representative for them now? Haha, JK, +1.

Comment: I represent whoever I damn well want to! :P  @Martin: thanks for accepting the answer, but my disclaimer still stands. Until Jeff publicly puts a +1 on it it's just the opinion of someone with a lot of experience in (online) legal stuff, but ***IANAL*** does apply  ;)